# Mysql table exists, but when shows 'It does not exist' when SELECT query is performed

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table named `options` in the database. It is listed in the table list. When I perform the query `show tables` then it is being displayed in the table list. But when I perform `select * from options` I am getting an error that `Table 'stillmanmvolvo.options' doesn't exist`. Please suggest me what to do.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you have to Change the schema?

Comment: It may exist somewhere, but it isn't in the database `stillmanmvolvo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `options` is still there:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM `stillmanmvolvo`;
```

If it's there, try this:

```
USE `stillmanmvolvo`;
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM `options`;
```

Don't forget the backticks!